# Angularjs Element find both select and input in one call - is the limit a single tag lookup?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, jqlite

I have a directive in which I want to find `<input/>` and `<select>` elements to bind a `blur` event to them. I know I this could be done with `ng-blur` but this question is really about the `angular.element` selector.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

    elem.find( 'input, select' ).bind( 'blur', someFunction); // doesn't work as input, select returns length 0

    // this works when separated
    elem.find( 'input' ).bind( 'blur', someFunction);
    elem.find( 'select' ).bind( 'blur', someFunction);

}
```

I guess the question is why doesn't the first way work?

the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) states:

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name 
>   from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

but doesn't say that it's limited to single tag lookups. Am I doing something wrong? Did I miss some documentation somewhere?

Comment: without the comma denotes a parent child relationship, so no, I haven't tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously we don't have the jQuery API here, so I'm not surprised it's *not working*. The docs are lacking - also no surprise there either. However, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L998), `.find()` is nothing more than a wrapper around [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). So - we don't buy ourselves much here. In other words, the compound selector isn't going to work...

```
// jqLite.js#L998
find: function(element, selector) {
    if (element.getElementsByTagName) {
        return element.getElementsByTagName(selector);
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: That clears things up on the why. Just wish I had docs explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `querySelectorAll`.

```
element[0].querySelectorAll('input, select')
```

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1196/